# "Invalid credentials" Google plus with request /plus/v1/people/me

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-plus

I'm doing sign in with Google+ and always I received the token correctly but when I want to make a request with this token to "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me" via curl. I always get the same error.

Code android to make login:

```
// Scope to get the token with the user information
public static final String SCOPE_GOOGLE_USER_INFORMATION = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
public static final String SCOPE_GOOGLE_PLUS_ME = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
public static final String SCOPE_GOOGLE_PLUS_LOGIN = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";
public static final String SCOPE_GOOGLE_PLUS_EMAIL = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
public static final String SCOPE = "oauth2:" + SCOPE_GOOGLE_USER_INFORMATION + " " + SCOPE_GOOGLE_PLUS_ME + " " + SCOPE_GOOGLE_PLUS_LOGIN + " " + SCOPE_GOOGLE_PLUS_EMAIL;


String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(activity, userEmail, SCOPE);
```

And then I make the curl request:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key={KEY}
```

Always I received the same error:

```
{
 "error": {
 "errors": [
 {
  "domain": "global",
  "reason": "authError",
  "message": "Invalid Credentials",
  "locationType": "header",
  "location": "Authorization"
 }
 ],
 "code": 401,
 "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

but If I do the same process via https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ works

Comment: At one point people were having issues when they included a bearer token and a key in the same request. What happens if you remove the key?

Comment: I can't remove the key because if no I receive other error. {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Google+ API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Google+ API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
 }
}

Comment: That sounds like the bearer token was generated from a project that does not have  the Google+ project enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You key and access token have to be from the same project. You can check the project number of the access token by plugging it into to: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=

Remove the plus.me scope as well, that is not needed. The email and profile scopes can be replaced with the strings "email" and "profile" respectively (no https://wwww.googleapis.com etc.). plus.login is reasonable, but if you're just getting basic profile, you don't need it - the profile scope will give you that from the plus API.